# Como posso fazer uma consulta com LIKE ou REGEXP ignorando palavras da tabela?

Tags: mysql

Eu tenho os seguintes dados em uma tabela

```
-------------------
**usuarios**
-------------------
nome
------------------
Wallace de Souza Vizerra
------------------------
Gustavo Carmo da Costa
```

Preciso retornar os registros da tabela `usuarios` que contenha o determinado valor no campo `nome`, porém preciso ignorar algumas palavras existentes nos valores do campo `nome`

Exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nome LIKE 'Wallace Souza Vizerra'
#Sem o "de" no nome
```

Gostaria que a consulta ao `nome` ignorasse as palavras `de`, `da`, `dos`, `das` existentes no banco.

Como posso fazer essa consulta, com LIKE ou REGEXP, excluíndo palavras?

Answer (score 2):

Tive um problema parecido aqui em minha empresa. Basicamente, aqui utilizamos duas formas para identificar homonimos com erros de digitação.

A primeira é a distancia levenshtein e a segunda é a função soundex().

### LEVENSHTEIN

Parafraseando a Wikipedia "a distância Levenshtein ou distância de edição entre dois "strings" é dada pelo número mínimo de operações necessárias para transformar um string no outro."

Por exemplo, a distância levenshtein entre "Guilherme Silva" e "Guilherme da Silva" é 3. Já entre "Maria Dores" e "Maria das Dores" é de 4.

Segue aqui o código para criar a função levenshtein() no Mysql.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION levenshtein( s1 VARCHAR(255), s2 VARCHAR(255) )
RETURNS INT
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE s1_len, s2_len, i, j, c, c_temp, cost INT;
DECLARE s1_char CHAR;
-- max strlen=255
DECLARE cv0, cv1 VARBINARY(256);
SET s1_len = CHAR_LENGTH(s1), s2_len = CHAR_LENGTH(s2), cv1 = 0x00, j = 1, i = 1, c = 0;
IF s1 = s2 THEN
RETURN 0;
ELSEIF s1_len = 0 THEN
RETURN s2_len;
ELSEIF s2_len = 0 THEN
RETURN s1_len;
ELSE
WHILE j <= s2_len DO
SET cv1 = CONCAT(cv1, UNHEX(HEX(j))), j = j + 1;
END WHILE;
WHILE i <= s1_len DO
SET s1_char = SUBSTRING(s1, i, 1), c = i, cv0 = UNHEX(HEX(i)), j = 1;
WHILE j <= s2_len DO
SET c = c + 1;
IF s1_char = SUBSTRING(s2, j, 1) THEN
SET cost = 0; ELSE SET cost = 1;
END IF;
SET c_temp = CONV(HEX(SUBSTRING(cv1, j, 1)), 16, 10) + cost;
IF c > c_temp THEN SET c = c_temp; END IF;
SET c_temp = CONV(HEX(SUBSTRING(cv1, j+1, 1)), 16, 10) + 1;
IF c > c_temp THEN
SET c = c_temp;
END IF;
SET cv0 = CONCAT(cv0, UNHEX(HEX(c))), j = j + 1;
END WHILE;
SET cv1 = cv0, i = i + 1;
END WHILE;
END IF;
RETURN c;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Para utilizar, no seu caso, você pode fazer a seguinte consulta:

```
SELECT * FROM usuario as us WHERE levenshtein(us.nome, 'Wallace Silva') < 5 //Ou outro indice. Coloquei 5 para que ele pegue somente nomes que tenham no maximo indice 4 na distancia levenshtein.
```

Caso você tenha no banco os seguintes registros

```
--------------------
1 Wallace Silva
2 Wallace João da Silva
3 Wallace das Silva
4 Guilherme da Silva
--------------------
```

A consulta irá retornar, neste caso, somente os registros 1 e 2.

### SOUNDEX

A função soundex(), é uma função que pode ser usada em pesquisas em bancos de dados aonde você conhece a pronuncia mas não exatamente como se escreve.

A soundex() já é nativa do Mysql e não precisamos criá-la manualmente.

No seu caso, a consulta ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
SELECT * FROM pessoa WHERE soundex(nome) = soundex('Wallace Silva')
```

O problema em usar a soundex() é que ela trabalha melhor com palavras em inglês e não funciona 100% em português.

### MODO COMBINADO

Podemos ainda criar uma consulta em que combinamos as duas formas de busca para que possamos ter uma maior probabilidade de acerto.

Podemos uliliza-la assim:

```
SELECT * FROM pessoa WHERE levenshtein(soundex(nome), soundex('Wallace Silva')) < 3
```

Ou ainda assim:

```
SELECT * FROM pessoa WHERE (levenshtein(nome, 'Wallace Silva') < 5) OR soundex(nome) = soundex('Wallace Silva')
```

### ALGUMAS CONSIDERAÇÕES

- Quando mais funções utilizarmos, mais processamento precisamos ter na máquina, ou seja, se criarmos um 'monstrinho' de consulta, ela pode demorar para rodar
- As duas funções possuem alguns pontos negativos, recomendo estudá-las bem e testar MUITO antes de implementar em algum código
- Até agora, essas foram as formas mais eficazes de buscar nomes semelhantes diretamente na consulta SQL que eu encontrei e que serviram para mim. Não significa que não existem outras melhores, não custa nada dar uma Googleada ;)

Enfim, espero ter ajudado! Bom proveito!

Answer (score 1):

Talvez não seja a forma mais adequada, mas até por questão de desempenho (pesquisar valores 'coringa' pode ser oneroso), a minha primeira ideia para esse problema seria armazenar um campo auxiliar 'corrigido', sem os termos que você quer eliminar. A busca seria feita neste campo (após corrigir, também, a string de busca).

Então teriamos

```
Nome                NomeTratado
____                _____________
Ricardo de Melo     Ricardo Melo
```

Novamente, essa seria minha primeira ideia. E acho que há uma boa chance que exista uma forma melhor.

Uma outra abordagem seria criar um índice com cada parte do nome. Isso pode ser interessante para fazer a busca retornar valores quando a pessoa digitar somente o sobrenome.

Answer (score 0):

Eu não entendi muito bem, mas você poderia fazer um like após % após digitar o último caracter.

`Select nome From usuarios Where nome Like 'Wallace%'`

ou para cada espaço você trocar ele pelo caracter "%" ou antes de fazer o Sql você troque essas preposições e substitua elas pelo %.

Existem várias maneiras de ser feito isso.

Comment: No caso, eu preciso que a ordem a palavra consultada no banco seja identidade a passada, apenas disconsiderando as palavras `de`,  `da`, `dos` e `das` no banco de dados. Então, "Luiz Silva" na consulta deveria retornar "Luiz da Silva" do banco. Entendeu?

Comment: E se você tivesse no banco "Luiz da Silva" e também tivesse "Luiz da Silva Santos", "Luiz da Silva dos Santos", os 3 deveriam ser retornados ?